# INDEX Function with fixed amount of results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to get the index function to give a fixed number of results?

I use the following formula to give all results from the Data sheet where A=3 and B=1.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Data!$D$2:$D,(Data!$A$2:$A=3)*(Data!$B$2:$B=1)))
```

I would like to show a fixed amount of results, instead of all the results. So for example I would like to INDEX the first 25 results that meet the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Data!$D$2:$D,(Data!$A$2:$A=3)*(Data!$B$2:$B=1)), 25, 1)
```

and see if that works?

See also: [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)

Comment: It works as I hoped. Thanks for letting me know about ARRAY_CONSTRAIN.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:D,"Select D where A=3 and B=1 Limit 25")
```